# How to edit Searchable Dictionary list?

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying android samples and i am wondering how to modify the dictionary list (database).  I can't seem to find the database file.  In the raw folder there is the definitions.txt, i tried to modify this but it doesn't seem to affect the search results.

please help.

many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Incrementing the database version should cause `onUpgrade()` method to be called.

Answer (score 2):

in the `DictionaryDatabase.java` change the database version.
I have changed it to `3 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;`
I have updated the definitions.txt file and after recompiling the project it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making changes in definitions.txt present at location `android-sdk_r15-windows\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-10\SearchableDictionary\res\raw` . When you open project in eclipse it copies project in its workspace. So the correct location is `<user>\workspace\SearchableDictionary\res\raw`

*Its a very late reply. Probably you could have found the answer all by yourself. But to maintain the balance on SO and to help people in similar kind of situation I am answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that the dictionary is only loaded once:

```
    private void loadDictionary() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    loadWords();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

So it doesn't matter that you have made changes, it won't load it a second time. Unless you uninstall the app and reinstall it. I don't know however how to fix, how to modify the code to load the dictionary each time (while I'm still developing the app), and I would be interested in a solution as well.

edit: I confirm that it works with simply incrementing the number of the database version, as answered by Scott and nikos. Thank you!